# Don't have any go routine but still getting "all goroutines are asleep -deadlock"

Tags: go

I was doing some experiments. Below is my code.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "time"
)

func main(){
  var a chan int
  a = make(chan int)
  for j:=0;j<10;j++{
    firstRoutine(a, j)
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Millisecond)
  }
}

func firstRoutine(chennel chan int, j int){
  i:=0
  fmt.Println("j = ", j, "chennel = ", chennel)
  chennel <- i
}
```

Output:

```
F:\Git\GitHub\GO\Prog\Concorrency>go run Channels.go
j =  0 chennel =  <nil>
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan send (nil chan)]:
main.firstRoutine(0x0, 0x0)
        F:/Git/GitHub/GO/Prog/Concorrency/Channels.go:24 +0x11f
main.main()
        F:/Git/GitHub/GO/Prog/Concorrency/Channels.go:14 +0x3f
exit status 2
```

I don't have any `gorutines` in my program but still getting this error.

Below program works, at least no goroutine error. only change is `go firstRoutine(a, j)`

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "time"
)

func main(){

  var a chan int
  a = make(chan int)
  for j:=0;j<10;j++{
    go firstRoutine(a, j)
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Millisecond)
  }
}

func firstRoutine(chennel chan int, j int){
  i:=0
  fmt.Println("j = ", j, "chennel = ", chennel)
  chennel <- i
}
```

Output:

```
F:\Git\GitHub\GO\Prog\Concorrency>go run Channels.go
j =  0 chennel =  0xc000048060
j =  1 chennel =  0xc000048060
j =  2 chennel =  0xc000048060
j =  3 chennel =  0xc000048060
j =  4 chennel =  0xc000048060
j =  5 chennel =  0xc000048060
j =  6 chennel =  0xc000048060
j =  7 chennel =  0xc000048060
j =  8 chennel =  0xc000048060
j =  9 chennel =  0xc000048060
```

Comment: @hobbs thanks for the info. Can you please explain how?

Comment: Please take the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/) which covers all the language basics, including why this code deadlocks.

Answer (score 2):

you are writing/sending data to the channel but you are not reading/receiving data from the same channel. A writing/reading to a channel blocks unless you read/write the data from it.

write a for loop that reads data from the channel a or use buffered channel

Adding some logs reveals the second case.

In the second case you have spawned 10 seperate go routines but all of them are blocked because the data is never read from the channel a, and after 10 iterations the for loop exits followed by the main function.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "time"
)

func main(){

  var a chan int
  a = make(chan int)
  for j:=0;j<10;j++{
    go firstRoutine(a, j)
    fmt.Println("sleeping")
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Println("awake")
  }
}

func firstRoutine(chennel chan int, j int){
  i:=0
  fmt.Println("j = ", j, "chennel = ", chennel)
  chennel <- i
  fmt.Println("pushed to channel"); // never gets printed
}
```

Upon using buffered channle:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "time"
)

func main(){

  var a chan int
  a = make(chan int, 11) // making a buffered channel of 11 elements
  for j:=0;j<10;j++{
    go firstRoutine(a, j)
    fmt.Println("sleeping")
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Println("awake")
  }
}

func firstRoutine(chennel chan int, j int){
  i:=0
  fmt.Println("j = ", j, "chennel = ", chennel)
  chennel <- i
  fmt.Println("pushed to channel"); // gets printed as buffer is bigger than the iterations, so no blocking
}
```